# Spring Kafka monitoring in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

As showcased in the following https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#streams-micrometer, Spring Kafka exposes various metrics via Micrometer.
Using it with Prometheus, I would like to display all these data in a more readable fashion using Grafana dashboards. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any support as most of the official ones use default metrics exposed via JMX. It seems there's already an open issue regarding Spring Kafka Observability: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2198. Any recent updates regarding that ? Or maybe there are already existing resources that I missed, therefore any feedback are more that welcome.